# Oracle Database Query cutting off first row

Tags: html, mysql, sql, vb.net, oracle

New here - so please pardon the potentially bad terminology. 
I'm currently working on a website using `VB.NET` and I am linking to my clients database using a query string connection(our two companies don't use the same database). Anyway, they are using an oracle DB and when I'm querying it through Visual Studio and filling a datatable, it doesn't seem to return one result.

So if I try:

```
Select count(*) from tableName;
```

OR

```
Select column, from tableName where rownum = 1;
```

Further note, that if I ran a query that returns multiple records, it will always delete the first row regardless of how it is ordered.

If you need more information in regards to how I set this up, please ask and I'll do my best, Thanks.

```
    Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)    (HOST=xxx.xxx.x.x)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME="NameGoesHere"))); User   Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"

    Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand

    cmd.Connection = conn
    Dim sQuery As New IO.StringWriter
    With sQuery
        .WriteLine("SELECT COUNT(*) ")
        .WriteLine("FROM tableName")
    End With

    cmd.CommandText = sQuery.ToString
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = conn

    Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(dr)

    conn.Dispose()
```

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Sorry I can't be more useful on that front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dr.Read()` probably moved the dr pointer to the next record.

So, `dt.Load(dr)` starts with always second row.

Comment: Welcome, was my guess only! Glad it worked for you.!